# Type Promose<Response> is missing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting this error and I am not sure why. In my dialog class I have the Promse and the fail logic. I am getting this build error any help would be great.

> Severity  Code    Description File    Project Line    Suppression State
> Error   TS2740  (TS) Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'JQueryPromise': state, always, done, fail, and 2 more.

```
 var responsePromse = this.agentManager.getStyleGuideByAgentId(this.model.Id);

        responsePromse.then((response) => {
            this.styleguideNote.AgentType = response.responseObject.Name;
        }).fail(() => {
                this.relatedTemplates.loadingState = 0;
        });
```

AgentManager

```
getStyleGuideByAgentId(Id: number): JQueryPromise<any> {
    var request = this.agentsService.getStyleGuideByAgentId(Id);
    console.log(request);
    return request;
}
```

AgentService

```
getStyleGuideByAgentId(Id: number) {
    var x = this.http.post(this.apiUrls.GetStyleGuideNotes, JSON.stringify(Id), { headers: ServiceBase.headers }).toPromise();
    return x;
}
```

Conroller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult GetStyleGuideNoteById(long agentId)
        {            
            var dbResult = StyleGuideNotesDataService.GetStyleGuideNoteById(agentId);

            var styleguideNote = dbResult
                .Select(x=>  new 
                {
                    Section =x.Section,
                    AgentType = x.AgentType,
                    Status = x.Status.Name
                })
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

            return Ok(styleguideNote);
        }
```

Comment: Uh, but this is Typescript I believe, is that Angular code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS Error message like this format `Type 'A' is missing following properties from  type 'B'` means that, you typed 'B' explicitly to a value, but type of the value is actually 'A'.

so, You typed something explicitly as `JQueryPromise`, but that thing was actually `Promise`.

I think this code makes error.

```
getStyleGuideByAgentId(Id: number): JQueryPromise<any> {
    var request = this.agentsService.getStyleGuideByAgentId(Id);
    console.log(request);
    return request;
}
```

I'm not sure but `getStyleGuideByAgentId` actually returns standard Promise, not JqueryPromise due to `toPromise()`

so, changing code like this might be solve your problem.

```
async getStyleGuideByAgentId(Id: number): Promise<any> {
    var request = await this.agentsService.getStyleGuideByAgentId(Id);
    console.log(request);
    return request;
}
```